# Update the value that I've get from local storage in chrome extension permanently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is the origin JSON set in the local storage

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "0":{"headers":[{
            "key": "test",
            "value": 1
        }]
    }}
}
```

Now I would like to update the header's value to **2** in this case

I've tried to modify the value from `get()` callback and use the `chrome.storage.local.set()` as following

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['profiles'], function(p){
    p['profiles'][0]['headers'][0]['value'] = 2; 
    const a = p['profiles']; 
    chrome.storage.local.set({'profiles':a}, 
        function(q){
            console.log(p)
        }
    )
})
```

The value has been updated to 2 successfully.

But after refreshing the page, the value reverts back to 1.

Any suggestion on how to update the local storage permanently?

Comment: what's your set code?

Comment: chrome.storage.local.get(['profiles'], function(p){
    p['profiles'][0]['headers'][0]['value'] = 2; 
    const a = p['profiles']; 
    chrome.storage.local.set({'profiles':a}, 
        function(q){
            console.log(p)
        }
    )
})

Comment: sorry, re-read your code I think it should work as-is, answer deleted. Have you check you didn't accidently overwrite the value on page reload? (you don't need `a` anyway)